# Failed to connect to parseapi.back4app.com port 443: Network is unreachable in php

Tags: php, parse-platform, localhost, back4app

I have used back4app for the backend database, and my website is properly working on live condition.

I want to check on localhost http url. How to check my website on locahost issue?

I have changed live url with localhost url

Comment: You should check to see if you have the correct url for your back4app service. You can always check `/health` to verify this. An example for localhost the url may be `http://localhost:1337/parse/health`. You should get a JSON response indicating the server is running.

Comment: Do you need to check parse server or your php web-site in the localhost?